# What are the desktop based Tools for UI work available today?

Tags: gui-design, design, tools, interface

What are the tools available to a UI developer? I know and use Photoshop, Fireworks, Balsamiq. I just recently came across Pixelmator and I'm checking it out. What else is out there? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Alex. I've marked this as a duplicate, but really such questions aren't suited to a Q&A website, you really want a forum or somesuch place for these questions. We really only deal with specific UX issues that you are looking for solutions to, not recommendations for different products I'm afraid.

Comment: @JonW You're right, but I'm not looking for a long discussion etc. Just a list of tools available right now that I can use to increase my productivity. It's a concrete problem and I'm looking for a concrete answer, which will also help other UX people. Thank you.

Comment: A list of examples / suggestions isn't a concrete answer though, it's just a list of suggestions. How do you know it any of those answers would be 'correct'? It's not really about what is helpful to other UX people, it's about what fits with a Q&A website. Have a read of the article [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for some more detailed reasoning about why such questions aren't suitable.